# Django template filters: apply floatformat to widthratio

Tags: django, django-templates

widthformat automatically rounds up.
However I would like to perform a division and round up to n decimal places in the template tag if possible.
For instance:

```
    <h4>Strike Rate: {% widthratio selected_replies user.projectreply_set.count 100 %}</h4>
```

Currently it returns an integer.

How would I apply floatformat here, or do I need to do this work in the view?

The alternative way using the model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    def get_strike_rate(self):
        selected_replies = self.user.projectreply_set.filter(is_selected_answer=True).count()
        my_replies = self.user.projectreply_set.count()
        if my_replies >0:
             return round((selected_replies/my_replies)*100.0,2)
        else:
             return 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no standard Django filter for that.
But you have few alternatives. First is as you said do math in the view.
Another one is using [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def div(value, div):
    return round((value / div) * 100, 2)
```

In template you can use it this way:

```
{{ a|div:b }}
```

Third option if you are using Django 1.8 and less is [django-mathfilters](https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters) you could try to use combinations of it's div and mult filters and Django [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filter.